# Append parameters to an existing url in Spring boot Java?

Tags: java, spring, api

I am trying to call a rest api and get the data from the api. I need to add dynamic parameters to the url in spring boot. I am a bit lost as how should I go about it. Can anyone kindly suggest me something?

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String consumeJSONString = restTemplate.getForObject("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=5.47686,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY"
, String.class);
```

I would like to append latlng and api key in the url dynamically. I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the following variation of `getForObject` method

```
restTemplate.getForObject(url, responseType, uriVariables);
```

So it becomes..

```
String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng={latlng}&key={key}";

Map<String, Object> uriVariables = new HashMap<>();
uriVariables.put("latlng", "5.47686,-73.961452");
uriVariables.put("key", "YOUR_API_KEY");

String consumeJSONString =  restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class, uriVariables);
```

Answer (score 0):

As i got a solution to dynamic variable
where this is a Rest Url

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/studentdetail")
public User detailStudent(@RequestParam(value = "userid", required = true) String userid) throws SQLException { /*your task goes here*/}
```

and this is what i m sending the dynamic params as userid which can be anything hopefully it will help u a lot

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9090/testpapers?userid=" + userid);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

conn.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
String s1=URLEncoder.encode(postDataParams, "UTF-8");

writer.write(s1);
writer.flush();
String line;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
{
  System.out.println(line);
}
writer.close();
reader.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Spring Framework, we have `org.springframework.web.util.UriTemplate` which does this in a structured way

1. Default URI in `application.properties`
   we can define a parametrized uri in properties file. For eg

> `url.template.google.maps`=https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=`{latitude}`,`{longitude}`&key=`{api_key}`

2. Initialize `UriTemplate`
   The template that we defined in properties file can now be read in a @PostConstruct block and stored in UriTemplate variable. I am saying @PostConstruct just to save trips to fetch the template for each request

```
    @Value("${url.template.google.maps}")  
    private String googleMapsUri;

    private UriTemplate googleMapsServiceUriTemplate;

    @PostConstruct  
    private void init() throws URISyntaxException {  
      googleMapsServiceUriTemplate= new UriTemplate(googleMapsUri);  
    }
```

3. `Expand variables` and get URI
   Now that we have everything, let's expand and get the uri

Given these values, call below method to get the URI

```
String latitudeValue = "5.47686";
String longitudeValue = "-73.961452";
String apiKeyValue = "api_key_value";
```

Below method would take the necessary values, create a map with these values and then expand the uri template to populate the values. We get a nicely structured URI this way.

```
pubic URI getGoogleMapsServiceUri(latitudeValue, longitudeValue, apiKeyValue) { 

  Map<String, String> templateVariables = new HashMap<>();
  templateVariables.put("latitude", latitudeValue); //could use a variable here 
  templateVariables.put("longitude", longitudeValue); //could use a variable here
  templateVariables.put("api_key", apiKeyValue); //could use a variable here

  URI googleMapsServiceUri = googleMapsServiceUriTemplate.expand(templateVariables); 
  System.out.println("URL is " + googleMapsServiceUri.getPath());
  
  return googleMapsServiceUri; 

}
```